# Redirect(url) not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In context of ASP.net MVC3, I have this line of code in a controller action, which tries to redirect to a particular url.

```
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

returnUrl is a string that contains "/Home/Index/". For Some reason the redirect is not taking place and I remain on the same screen.  I tried removing the trailing slash but no success. Any ideas why the Redirect does not take place?

Answer (score 21):

The `Redirect` method is intended to be used to redirect to external urls of your site and by passing it an absolute url. If you need to redirect to another controller action that belongs to your site it would be better to use this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

This way you are no longer hardcoding urls and your code is less fragile to route changes.

This being said, if you are invoking the controller action that performs this redirect with AJAX you cannot expect it to redirect the browser anywhere => it will obviously stay on the same page. The AJAX request will succeed following all redirects and in the success callback you will get the final HTML of the `/Home/Index` url as if it was requested without AJAX.

If you want to redirect in the success callback of an AJAX call you could have your controller action return for example a JSON object indicating the target url you want to redirect to:

```
return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
```

and in your callback use the `window.location.href` function:

```
success: function(result) {
    window.location.href = result.redirectToUrl;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for that exhaustive reply. I am not using AJAX here, so we can rule out the second part of your reply. Ideally I would like to use RedirectToAction() but I am using Authentication here, where I am getting returnUrl as the originally requested page. This original request can be any page in my application. So I can't just hardcode the Controller and Action in RedirectToAction().There is one option for me to work out the Controller and Action part from returnUrl using string manipulation techniques (even that would be very difficult) but I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Nirvan, instead of sending a returnUrl string variable send 2 variables which are controller and action. This way you could build the required url. If not try using an absolute url with Redirect like `http://yoursite.com/home/index`.

Comment: @Darain, Sorry I was not very clear about the authentication stuff. The asp.net authentication by default keeps track of which page was originally requested prior to login. I do not myself populate the returnUrl. For example assume that the user tries to access /Home/Index before logging in. The Asp.net authentication steps in and redirects to login page of my application. This is where the server populates the returnUrl as "/Home/Index". So you see I get only a string (regurnUrl) in my Login Controller which contains the url of the originally requested page.

Comment: @Nirvan, the default project template uses Redirect in the LogOn action and that works correctly. Maybe the problem's somewhere else with your code.

Comment: Even I think so. I will try to check my code specially as regards to authorization. Anyway, I would be using redirect for AJAX call in my upcomming module, so I have the solution ready as indicated by your first reply! Thanks for that.

Comment: I am also stuck with exact issue, We are using JQuery Mobile here, and same Logon page, Redirect causes no change in URL, and things go haywire afterwards... ny standard solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck on the SAME LOGIN SCREEN after supplying valid logon credentials, it is possible you have not set the Forms authentication cookie.

Whenever you use Redirect or RedirectToLocal in your Login actionmethods, make sure you call in the following order:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

This ensures, the cookie is set before Redirecting, otherwise the client will treat as if the user is not logged in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in MVC 5, the standard login.cshtml markup was working fine. I was only having problems when I was including the html markup for a template I had bought. So what I did was to start replacing the login.cshtml code bit by bit. As it turns out the problem was because the template included a JQuery plugin called "rd-mailform" and this was causing the issue.

This didn't work:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "rd-mailform form-modern form-darker", role = "form" }))

And this worked:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-modern form-darker", role = "form" }))

Sometimes designers that create these templates mix functionality with design, so you have to watch out for that.

Answer (score 0):

@Nirvan, i had the same problem. after thorough research i realized that the default login settings that come with the mvc template were conflicting with my login settings. i never found out how to solve it and decided to restart the project i was working on with a blank mvc project.(i didnt want to use the default login setings AND CODE done by mycrosoft).
it worked smoothly.
@Nirvan,if your using mvc template your code is most likely fine

Comment: You need to give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer