# Redirect to returnURL not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In reference to [this posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402701/redirecturl-not-working)

The answer given does not work for me and I am having the same problem here.

I'm also using aspnet authentication and a user can try to navigate to any page on the site, specifically it is very common for a user to navigate to something like /mycontroller/myaction/25 where 25 is an account or product identifier that is used very often by that user.

If the user is currently not authenticated when trying to access that url, they are redirected to the logon screen. After logon, the redirect(returnURL) is NOT navigating the user to the requested page. The page stays on the login screen.

The url that a user would paste into the address bar before login could be:

```
http://localhost:4082/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fProduct%2fEdit%2f59
```

After entering credentials and debugging to see that the credentials were authenticated, the URL is the same

```
http://localhost:4082/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fProduct%2fEdit%2f59
```

The difference between the stock mvc project and mine is that I have a little more than just a logon happening at the login action. Here is my code: (I've obviously broken something by making each function small and contained)

```
public ActionResult LogOn() {
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    var model = new LogOnViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        try {
            return AttemptToAuthenticateUser(model, returnUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

private ActionResult AttemptToAuthenticateUser(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    var membershipUser = GetUserFromMembershipProvider(model.Username, false);
    var audit = new LoginAudit(model.Username, model.Password, Request.Browser.Browser, Request.Browser.Type, Request.UserHostAddress);
    VerifyUserAccountIsApprovedNotLockedOut(membershipUser);
    AuthenticateCredentials(model, audit);
    AuditLogon(audit, model.Username, true);
    return ForwardToLogonResultAction(membershipUser, returnUrl, model.RememberMe);
}

internal static MembershipUser GetUserFromMembershipProvider(string username, bool isUserCurrentlyLoggedIn) {
    var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(username, isUserCurrentlyLoggedIn);
    if (membershipUser == null)
        throw new Exception("The user account was not found");
    return membershipUser;
}

internal static void VerifyUserAccountIsApprovedNotLockedOut(MembershipUser membershipUser) {
    if (membershipUser.IsLockedOut || !membershipUser.IsApproved)
        throw new Exception("This account has been disabled or has been locked out. Please contact Administration for support");
}

private void AuthenticateCredentials(LogOnViewModel model, LoginAudit audit) {
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) { }
    else {
        AuditLogon(audit, model.Username, false);
        throw new Exception("The user name or password provided is incorrect");
    }
}

private void AuditLogon(LoginAudit audit, string username, bool isSuccessfullyAuthenticated) {
    if (isSuccessfullyAuthenticated)
        audit.Password = string.Empty;
    audit.Save(username);
}

private ActionResult ForwardToLogonResultAction(MembershipUser currentMembershipUser, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe) {
    if (IsPasswordOnAccountTemporary((Guid)currentMembershipUser.ProviderUserKey))
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "ChangePassword");
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return ForwardUserToHomePage(currentMembershipUser.UserName, rememberMe);
}

private bool IsPasswordOnAccountTemporary(Guid userGUID) {
    var profile = new Profile(userGUID);
    return profile.IsTemporaryPassword;
}
```

Update

I tried changing the Post action so that the returnURL check is in the same action but it still doesn't work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            try {
                AttemptToAuthenticateUser(model, returnUrl);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) 
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                return ForwardUserToHomePage(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Update 2
Changing my code back to the way I orginally had it, it works perfect... so this tells me that it has more to do with the ordering of the what I'm doing than anything else... going to try to re-order the smaller methods to match the order of this action and see what happens

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            MembershipUser currentUser;
            var audit = new LoginAudit(model.Username, model.Password, Request.Browser.Browser, Request.Browser.Type, Request.UserHostAddress);
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) {
                audit.Password = string.Empty;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
                currentUser = Membership.GetUser(model.Username, true);
                if (currentUser != null && currentUser.ProviderUserKey != null) {
                    var profile = new Profile((Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey);
                    if (profile.IsTemporaryPassword)
                        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "ChangePassword");
                }
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            currentUser = Membership.GetUser(model.Username, false);
            if (currentUser != null && (currentUser.IsLockedOut || !currentUser.IsApproved)) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "This account has been locked out. Please contact ELM Administration for support.");
            }
            else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
            audit.Save(model.Username);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Udpate 3

This fixed it, got it on my own :-)

```
    private void AuthenticateCredentials(LogOnViewModel model, LoginAudit audit) {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
        }
        else {
            AuditLogon(audit, model.Username, false);
            throw new Exception("The user name or password provided is incorrect");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to set the cookie earlier than I was before. I was setting the cookie only when I called ForwardUserToHomePage method where the cookie was being set and then redirect to home/index. But since that method was never being called as I was doing a redirect(returnUrl) instead and the cookie wasn't set. Since it wasn't set, the redirect failed as the client believed the used to not yet be logged in, hence the login page was "being hit again" in actuality.

Modified my AuthenticateCredentials method to be:

```
    private void AuthenticateCredentials(LogOnViewModel model, LoginAudit audit) {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
        }
        else {
            AuditLogon(audit, model.Username, false);
            throw new Exception("The user name or password provided is incorrect");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

In your `Logon` View, are you passing the url to the HttpPost method ?

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { returnUrl= Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
 {
     //your form elements
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 }
```

Comment: I am using beginform with no parameters just @Html.BeginForm()

Comment: @CDSmith: Your HttpPost action method is expecting a parameter called returnUrl so you should pass that. Change your form like my answer.

Comment: I shouldn't need to change that because - see update - in my original action, the form is not passing the returnUrl and it works perfect. Out of the box MVC3, the returnUrl does not have to specified in the form. So since the original action works without specifying it then I can see the problem is more about the ordering of all the junk I'm doing. I'm suspicious that it has something to do with the cookie being set early in the original action.

Comment: Yep that was it, I modified the AuthenticateCredentials method and it works perfect not.. see update 3